# Как одновременно записать модель в room и получить ее во view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Получаю модель с помощью retrofit, записываю в базу данных и сразу хочу получить во view, выходит ошибка null т.к. функции записи и чтения запускаю одновременно. Решил с помощью delay(1000), но как сделать правильно? Если будет плохое интернет-соединение, то одной секунды не хватит... Хотелось бы узнать как вообще принято в разработке, обязательно записывать в бд и получать от туда, или можно напрямую из ретрофита передать во view если речь не о списке, а об одной модели?

```
Dao:

@Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table WHERE id = :id")
    fun getMovie(id: Int): LiveData<MovieDbModel>
```

Ошибку получаю в репозитории, когда пытаюсь трансформировать LiveData модель бд в LiveData модель UseCase:

```
override fun getMovie(): LiveData<MovieUseCaseModel> {
        return Transformations.map(localDataSourceRepository.getMovie(1)) {
            mapper.mapMovieDbModelToMovieUseCaseModel(it)}
    }
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: it must not be null
        at com.example.kplist.data.repositoryImpl.RepositoryImpl.getMovie$lambda-3(RepositoryImpl.kt:86)
```

Comment: Правильно подписаться на изменения в Room и он сам сообщит подписчику когда новые данные кто-либо сохранит либо изменит.

Answer (score 0):

1. ошибка заключается в том, что вам прилетает null в LiveData и это бывает. а вот ваши слушатели не ожидают, что может быть null.
   чтобы это исправить, просто укажите в вашем интерфейсе что LD может быть nullable

   ```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table WHERE id = :id")
   fun getMovie(id: Int): LiveData<MovieDbModel?>
   ```
2. можно ли напрямую из ретрофита? да, конечно можно. БД, в вашем случае, нужна если провалится сетевой запрос, а юзер уже когда-то смотрел инфу про этот фильм. тут то вы и подтяните данные. но в такой реализации через LiveData это будет весьма некрасиво.

Comment: Wlad, спасибо, помогло